# Kivy ColorWheel widget

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I want to call a method whenever i click on the ColorWheel widget, i've tried giving it a ButtonBehavior and using on_release but that takes the color changing functionality out of the widget. I've also tried on_touch_down but that calls the method when any location on the screen is pressed and that is something i don't want. I want to know if there's an attribute that can be used when only the widget is clicked like 'on_press' or something close

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Frame(Widget):
    def update(self, *args):
        color = self.ids['colory']
        print(color.color)

Builder.load_string('''
<Frame>
    ColorWheel:
        id: colory
        size: 240, 240
        pos: 30, 30
        on_press: root.update()
''')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Frame()

MainApp().run()
```

something of such. Thank you.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ButtonBehavior overwrites the on_touch_down, on_touch_move and on_touch_up so if you use it the standard task of ColorWheel will not work correctly, in those cases it is better to create custom events as shown below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.colorpicker import ColorWheel

class CustomColorWheel(ColorWheel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomColorWheel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_press')
        self.register_event_type('on_release')

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        res = super(CustomColorWheel, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        if res is None:
            self.dispatch('on_press')
        return res

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        super(CustomColorWheel, self).on_touch_up(touch)
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and touch.grab_current is self:
            self.dispatch('on_release')
            return True

    def on_press(self):
        pass

    def on_release(self):
        pass

class Frame(Widget):
    def update(self):
        color = self.ids['colory']
        print(color.color)

Builder.load_string('''
<Frame>:
    CustomColorWheel:
        id: colory
        size: 240, 240
        pos: 30, 30
        on_press: root.update()
        on_release: print('on_release')
''')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Frame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Another simpler option is to use `on__hsv`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Frame(Widget):
    def update(self):
        color = self.ids['colory']
        print(color.color)


Builder.load_string('''
<Frame>:
    ColorWheel:
        id: colory
        size: 240, 240
        pos: 30, 30
        on__hsv: root.update()
''')


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Frame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the on__hsv attribute and it works. I'd try the other answer later